# how to run xmllint within sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3, xmllint

I know how to use xmllint from the command line for validating an xml file against an XSD:

```
             xmllint --schema exampleschema.xsd example.xml
```

Now I downloaded and installed sublimelinter and the xmllint plugin for my sublime text editor.

However, I can't figure out how to run xmllint from sublime text. What do I have to do to have an xml-file validated against a schema?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to ensure that you're using [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) to install all your plugins. [`xmllint`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/xmllint) is only for Sublime Text 2, and should not be used.

Along with [`SublimeLinter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter), you need to install [`SublimeLinter-xmllint`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-xmllint). Make sure you read the *full* documentation both for SublimeLinter and SublimeLinter-xmllint to ensure everything, including paths, are set up correctly. You can then configure your desired command-line arguments using [linter settings](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/linter_settings.html).

Comment: I have installed Package Control and SublimeLinter-xmllint and I read the whole documentation. My question is this: where is the interface for using SublimeLinter-xmllint? I am looking for a new button or whatever within my sublime text editor so that I can use all the cool stuff I have installed. My problem is simply that I have installed everything according to the documentation but the interface of my sublime text editor has not changed at all - so I don't no how to access the stuff I have installed.

Comment: Let us know if you found a solution.